# Water volume sum

Tags: arithmetic, volume

Let's start by quoting the question.

> Water flows at the rate of 10 m per minute through a cylindrical pipe of diameter 5mm. How much time would it take for it to fill a conical vessel of diameter 40 cm and depth 24 cm?

I just don't get what the question means. After doing many sums on volume, I can work it out for sure. But what has 10 m to do with a volume sum?

I'll be highly grateful to anyone who could lead me into the right track.

Comment: Can you find the volume of the cone ?   What is the rate of flow of water in terms of volume through the pipe ?

Comment: Volume of cone = 1/3* pi *r^2 * h, so?

Comment: The rate of 10m per min will help you to find the 'time' after you have calculated the volumes.

Comment: Find the volume.  Then you know the rate of fill. From that you can find the time

Comment: Volume = 10,048 cm3. Then? Is it 10m3 per minute actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

The quantity of water that flows in a minute is $\Phi=va$ where $v$ is the  rate of flow $v=1000\; cm/min$ and $a$ is the area of the section of the pipe $a=\pi r^2= 0.25 \pi \; cm^2$ .

The volume of the vessel is $V=\frac{1}{3}\pi R^2h$

can you do from this?

Comment: @Emilio_Novati, thanks for that! I'd like to learn why a = 0.25pi, if possible. Again, thanks a ton.

Comment: The radius is $5 \; mm=0.5 \; cm$ so $r^2= 0.25 \; cm^2$

Answer (score 0):

Note the rate of flow is also the height of the pipe . so calculate the volume of cone by $1/3pir^2h$. so 10 metre of water enters vessel every minute so  time it would  take to fill this volume is $x/10$ where $x$ is the calculated volume of conical vessel.